# Jpx and jpf image convert to jpg not converting in aws ec2

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, imagemagick

I am not able to convert image format jpx and jpf into jpg on aws ubuntu 16.01 instead i am able to do this on my local machine 
by this code:
to know the tool to convert

```
convert -list configure | grep DELEGATES
```

and use convert command after install imagemagick

```
convert rose.jpx rose.jpg
```

but not able to do on aws ec2 same os.

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: Aren't you able to install imagemagick? If so please post the full error messages. If not, i.e., you were able to install imagemagick but convert doesn't work, please post those error messages.

Comment: I have installed imagemagick already and then i used this convert but its working on my local virtual machine but not working on aws ec2 ubuntu 16.01

Comment: Do you get any error message ? What is the output of `convert --version` ?